How can I force the screen of my Surface Tablet ON using Powershell
I have a surface tablet I'm trying to set up with my home cameras. I set it up to turn off the screen completely so it doesn't risk burnout of the screen. Not just blank screen, but OFF.
When the front door detects motion, it runs these scripts to try to force the screen back on
Based on posts I've found so far, I have a two stage process as follows:
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File  C:\temp\ForceScreenOn.ps1

This for setting the execution policy, and then this for theoretically actually making the screen come on.
(Add-Type -MemberDefinition "[DllImport(""user32.dll"")]`npublic static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);" -Name "Win32SendMessage" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru)::SendMessage(0xffff, 0x0112, 0xF170, -1)
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$wsh.SendKeys('+{F15}')

This has been incredibly hard to test because I have to wait for the screen to go off completely and then trigger the cameras outside. It seemed to work when I tested it, but then when I mounted the wall, the screen goes off, but it doesn't come back on.
Am I on the wrong path here? What's the right way to force a screen on? Am I close?

The SendMessage call looks right - perhaps it's the front door motion detector trigger that isn't firing correctly?
